# How to use BeautifulSoup to get only strings from tags that have specific start?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping usernames and all of them are in the same a tag and their hrefs all start the same, like this:

```
<a href="http://lolprofile.net/summoner/eune/Sadastyczny" class="link5">Sadastyczny</a>
```

I tried finding only if they have the class link5 but there are other values that have that class which I don't want to scrape. So is there a way to search for all the tags which have the

```
href="http://lolprofile.net/summoner"
```

in them but not the rest since that obviously is different for every username?

Comment: `links = [i for i in soup.find_all('a') if i.attrs.get('class') == 'link5']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments).

Using a regular expression you can match the sites. If you have never heard of regular expressions you can use this:

`soup.find_all(href=re.compile("http://lolprofile.net/summoner/*"))`

Don't forget to import the `re`-module!

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I'll look into the re module, thanks a lot!